# Bad mask for Cisco router interface

Tags: cisco, routing

I'm not too clear on subnetting rules and experienced an error when I tried to assign `148.26.1.176/28` to an interface on my *Cisco router*. Can someone please explain why it was not allowing me to assign this address to the interface?

I receive an error saying:

`Bad mask /28 for address 148.26.1.176`

Comment: I strongly suggest changing your title for something that summarize your question. As is I will not event read the actual question...

Comment: I also suggest you change the title to something which might make people want to help you.

Comment: I find it somewhat amusing that the IP address here is exactly the same as the one in the 4,5 year old duplicate. Is this from some bad example somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

/28 means that you are assigning the last 4 bits to the host part of the address.

176 in binary is `10110000`.

The last 4 bits are zero, it means that it is the **network address** of the subnet.

You can't assign to a device the first address (network address) or the last address (broadcast address) of a subnet.

---

A little trick:

In this case, the 4 bits for host part, means that you will have **16** address on each subnet.

Then divide `176/16`, if the division is exact without decimals then is a network address and can't be used.